# E2E Coverage for the E2E protractor cases

Tags: angularjs, protractor

We have huge E2E test cases with Protractor for our Angular App. Can anyone suggest how we can calculate the Coverage for these test cases?

P.S: They are separated from the code and are more into E2E and Selenium-based.
Please pardon if a noob question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Grunt plugin [grunt-protractor-coverage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-protractor-coverage) which provides code coverage metrics for Protractor tests.

If you are using Angular CLI, code coverage for Protractor isn't supported out of the box yet. There is a feature request to add code coverage for e2e tests [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6286)

Unfortunately, as your product code and test code don't occupy the same code base, generating code coverage automatically will be difficult.

An alternative to code coverage for e2e tests is functional/feature coverage. This can be achieved by determining the number of user functions/features your application has and how many of those functions/features are covered by an e2e test. It is then possible to calculate the percentage of functions/features covered. I'm not aware of an automated tool which will do this however.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the e2e coverage by pre-instrumenting the code with Istanbul/nyc and then downloading the coverage info via protractor. You can find a sample solution here:
https://github.com/edvlucas/angular-e2e-coverage